# Why is my code hanging indefinitely?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to run the following code that uses Nokogiri, but it is getting stuck when it hits the 161th iteration. List is a set of nodes that were created after parsing a file.

I am left wondering why that is happening, could it be that it is running out of memory? What else could I check if it is hanging indefinitely.

```
for i in 0...list.length
  puts i
  # puts list[i].inner_html
  while isReady(list[i])
    list[i].inner_html = "#{list[i+1].inner_html}"
    list[i+1].remove
  end
end
```

***Issue resolved*** I just realized that list[i+1].remove was not removing, and that's why it was hanging indefinitely in that while loop. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: You'll need to provide more context for what you are doing. How big is the document? What are you trying to do? What is `isReady()`, because that is what is looping, unless list.length is absurdly big, or list.length + the time for `isReady` to run is greater than your patience.

Comment: Totally agree with the Tim Man. Besides that, change your first line to `list.each_index do |i|`. That is more comprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what happens when i == list.length, and list[i+1].remove() is called?  that looks troublesome.